# How to capture ESC and Enter keys being pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with get when user enter <kbd>ESC</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. What I want to do is edit nick in place using by AJAX, jQuery.

For example I have a code in my HTML:

```
<div id="nick">Change Nick</div>
```

Next is my code in JS

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){    
  var oldText, newText;    
  $("#nick").bind("dblclick", replaceHTML);    
  function replaceHTML() {
    $("#nick").empty();
    $("#nick").append("<form><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control input-lg\" /></form><button class=\"btn btn-default\" type=\"button\" id=\"btnSave\">Save</button><button class=\"btn btn-default\" type=\"button\" id=\"btnDiscard\">Discard</button>");
    $("#nick").unbind("dblclick", replaceHTML);
  }    
  $('#btnDiscard').click(function() {
    alert('rr');
  });    
});
</script>
```

Ok now when i DBL click on Nick Change i replace to input text. But when i click on Discard i have no `alert('rr')`. When i put manualy the same code what is in `append(" ")` when i click Discard i have alert.

What should i do ? Because maybe i should recive only on press Enter as save and esc as disable. How can i fix it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to bind the action before the element has entered the dom. You need to move the click bind into the function:

```
function replaceHTML() {
  $("#nick").empty();
  $("#nick").append("<form><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control input-lg\" /></form><button class=\"btn btn-default\" type=\"button\" id=\"btnSave\">Save</button><button class=\"btn btn-default\" type=\"button\" id=\"btnDiscard\">Discard</button>");
  $("#nick").unbind("dblclick", replaceHTML);

  $('#btnDiscard').click(function() {
    alert('rr');
  });
}
```

EDIT:

If you do want to listen for the escape or enter key use the following:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27) {
    // esc
  }   
  else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    // enter
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/n3AizJUB1ws3S8b8izg8?p=preview) example, listening for Escape and Enter key.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var oldText, newText;

  $("#nick").bind("dblclick", replaceHTML);

  function replaceHTML() {
    oldText = $("#nick").html();

    $("#nick").empty();
    $("#nick").append("<form><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control input-lg\" value=\"" + oldText + "\"/></form><button class=\"btn btn-default\" type=\"button\" id=\"btnSave\">Save</button><button class=\"btn btn-default\" type=\"button\" id=\"btnDiscard\">Discard</button>");
    $("#nick").unbind("dblclick", replaceHTML);

    bindEvents();
  }

  function bindEvents() {
    $('#btnDiscard').on('click', function() {
      cancel();
    });

    $('#btnSave').on('click', function() {
      save();
    });

    $('form input').on('keydown', function(event) {
      var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;

      if (keyCode == 27) {
        cancel();
      }
      else if (keyCode == 13) {
        // You have to prevent the form to make a submit
        event.preventDefault();
        save();
      }
    });
  }

  function save(newText) {
    newText = $('form input').val();

    unbindFormEvents();

    $('#nick').html(newText);
  }

  function cancel() {
    unbindFormEvents();

    $('#nick').html(oldText);
  }

  function unbindFormEvents() {
    $('#btnDiscard').off('click');
    $('#btnSave').off('click');
    $('form input').off('keyup');

    $('#nick').bind('dblclick', replaceHTML);
  }

});
```

Comment: Do U know why when i click SAVE button is ok, but when i press ENTER is ok but web is reloaded.

Comment: Because the input is within a form, and when you hit the enter key on an input, the form triggers the submit event. This is the default behavior. You need to listen for the keydown event. If you listen for the keyup event, the submit event is triggered first

Answer (score 0):

You're adding HTML elements dynamically to the webpage, but your Javascript executes immediately. So `$('#btnDiscard').click( function(){ ... })` executes before it has anything to bind onto.

One solution is to use a delegate element to listen for this click instead. Since you're using jQuery it's pretty simple to bind your event to a delegate:

```
$('body').on('click', '#btnDiscard', function(event){
    console.log(event);
});
```

In this case the body is the delegate, listening for a click coming from an element with the btnDiscard id. It doesn't matter whether `#btnDiscard` existed when that event was bound to `body`.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3dLLjed3/) of it working.